# Sentencia de INSERT Mysqli Prepared, que tiene de malo?

Tags: mysqli

Poseo la siguiente sentencia para insertar en mi tabla, me da error

> Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object

justo en el inicio de la sentencia

Hice un echo de los valores que uso POST y todos se guardan bien

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO SANCIONES (
      cedula_sancionado, 
      cedula_sancionador, 
      cedula_superior, 
      articulo_falta, 
      aparte_falta, 
      documento_seleccion, 
      fecha_inicio, 
      fecha_termino, 
      dias_sancion, 
      aclaratoria_sancion, 
      estado_sancion_id,
      medida_id,
      articulo_circunstancia,
      agravante_seleccion, 
      atenuante_seleccion, 
      total_demerito, 
      estado_id)) 
      VALUE (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param(""iiiiisssisiiissdi"
 ,$cedula1
 ,$cedula2
 ,$cedula3
 ,$articulo_falta
 ,$aparte_falta
 ,$documentos_implode
 ,$fecha_inicio
 ,$fecha_termino
 ,$dias
 ,$aclaratoria
 ,$estado_sancion
 ,$tipo_medida
 ,$tipo_circunstancia
 ,$agravantes_implode
 ,$atenuantes_implode
 ,$total_demerito
 ,$estado);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
```

Ejemplo de valores arrojados con un echo

```
8644097
8644097
8644097
36
1
2-1-3-4-5-6
13/03/2017
25/03/2017
12
qwrqwr qwr qwr qwr qwr wq
1
2
40
3-4
0.45
6
```

Tabla Sanciones:

```
id_sancion  int(11)
cedula_sancionado   int(10)
cedula_sancionador  int(10)
cedula_superior int(10)
articulo_falta  int(2)
aparte_falta    int(2)
documento_seleccion varchar(11)
fecha_inicio    date NULL
fecha_termino   date NULL
dias_sancion    int(3)
aclaratoria_sancion text
estado_sancion_id   int(3)
fecha_conforme  date
fecha_proceso   date
medida_id   int(2)
articulo_circunstancias int(2)
agravante_seleccion varchar(5)
atenuante_seleccion varchar(5)
total_demerito  double
estado_id   int(2)
```

Comment: creo que se sobra un espacio detrás de estado_id.

Comment: El problema seguramente esta "$conexion, ya que te debe estar regresando false y por eso te dice que al no ser un objecto no es posible hacer llamadas, pon el codigo de $conexion para verlo

Comment: En `estado_id))` debes quitar un parentesis y usar `VALUES` en vez de `VALUE`

Comment: David no era por el espacio, era el ) parentesis extra Sergio1871 hasta ahora devuelve false es la sentencia, no la conexion @Igor le faltaba la s, pero igual da el mismo error, pero ahora en el bind_param->

Comment: @VictorA.desconozco PHP, pero, ¿has buscado qué significa el error? Mira esta [respuesta en inglés](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4488100/4092887) la cual te podría ayudar a resolver ese error. _(el primero te lo dijo el usuario Igor en su [comentario](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/54952/sentencia-de-insert-mysqli-prepared-que-tiene-de-malo#comment98131_54952).)_

Comment: El error indica que `$stmt = $conexion->prepare()` no devolvio un objeto valido. Puedes llamar var_dump($stmt) luego del `prepare()` y ver que esta obteniendo.

Comment: probe la funcion y sale FALSE, habian dos problemas, el primero en la sentencia agregaba un campo para ser insertado y la variable no la habia agregado al bind_param y el otro era que hay un campo que le faltaba una letra, era circunstancias y puse circunstancia

ya funciono

Comment: si quedo solucionado tu problema deberías poner la solución en una respuesta por si alguien tiene el mismo problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque ya sabes de donde proviene el fallo, te voy a dejar un ejemplo muy funcional para un futuro, al menos te ahorrara dolor de cabeza, es un método para encontrar a veces más fácil los pequeños fallos de despiste que uno tiene fácilmente con tanto código. Al menos te va aclarar donde debes buscar el fallo en tu sentencia `prepare()`.

**Un posible ejemplo:**

```
<?php
    //Sentencia preparada.
    $stmt = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO SANCIONES (cedula_sancionado, cedula_sancionador, cedula_superior, articulo_falta, aparte_falta, documento_seleccion, fecha_inicio, fecha_termino, dias_sancion, aclaratoria_sancion, estado_sancion_id, medida_id, articulo_circunstancia, agravante_seleccion, atenuante_seleccion, total_demerito, estado_id) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");

    if (false===$stmt) { #Comprobación.
        exit('La sentencia preparada fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }

    //Ligamos parametros marcadores.
    $rc = $stmt->bind_param("iiiiisssisiiissdi",$cedula1,$cedula2,$cedula3,$articulo_falta,$aparte_falta,$documentos_implode,$fecha_inicio,$fecha_termino,$dias,$aclaratoria,$estado_sancion,$tipo_medida,$tipo_circunstancias,$agravantes_implode,$atenuantes_implode,$total_demerito,$estado);

    if (false===$rc) { #Comprobación.
        exit('la función bind_param() fallo: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
    }

    //Ejecutamos sentencia.
    $rc = $stmt->execute();

    if (false===$rc) { #Comprobación.
        exit('la sentencia fallo al ejecutar: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));  
    } else {
        echo "Los datos se insertaron correctamente a la Base de datos :)";
    }
    $stmt->close(); //Cerramos sentencia.


?>
```

> Fatal error: Call to a member function `bind_param()` on a non-object

Como dice el mensaje de error, `$stmt` parece no ser un objeto.
Intenta depurar esto utilizando `var_dump($stmt)`, justo después de la llamada preparada.

Como has mencionado la llamada preparada falla y por lo que devuelve false -  false no es un objeto, por lo que no se puede llamar a `bind_parm()` en eso.

[Fuente SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4488035/call-to-a-member-function-bind-param-on-a-non-object)

Comment: excelente muchas gracias :)

Answer (score 0):

El principal problema fue que *agravantes_seleccion* no estaba recibiendo el valor, y como no es `NULL` este generaba error.

Lo segundo `$tipo_circunstancia` no era el nombre correcto, este era `$tipo_circunstancias`.

Por lo tanto, daba *error* ya que faltaba por agregar los valores de estas variables al `bind_param()`.

**Quedo así:**

```
$stmt = $conexion->prepare("INSERT INTO SANCIONES (
      cedula_sancionado, 
      cedula_sancionador, 
      cedula_superior, 
      articulo_falta, 
      aparte_falta, 
      documento_seleccion, 
      fecha_inicio, 
      fecha_termino, 
      dias_sancion, 
      aclaratoria_sancion, 
      estado_sancion_id,
      medida_id,
      articulo_circunstancia,
      agravante_seleccion, 
      atenuante_seleccion, 
      total_demerito, 
      estado_id)) 
      VALUE (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
$stmt->bind_param("iiiiisssisiiissdi"
 ,$cedula1
 ,$cedula2
 ,$cedula3
 ,$articulo_falta
 ,$aparte_falta
 ,$documentos_implode
 ,$fecha_inicio
 ,$fecha_termino
 ,$dias
 ,$aclaratoria
 ,$estado_sancion
 ,$tipo_medida
 ,$tipo_circunstancias
 ,$agravantes_implode
 ,$atenuantes_implode
 ,$total_demerito
 ,$estado);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
}
```

Comment: ¿Estás seguro que te funciona correctamente el código? sigo viendo algún error ya mencionado. Como el paréntesis extra *))* ante de *VALUE* y otro pequeño error, la tienes en *bind_param(""*, tiene una comilla doble extra también.

Comment: jejeje no me habia percatado, es que copie y pegue el mismo codigo de la respuesta, pues no lo comente por mi tablet y no tenia el codigo a la mano.